# Slack - Interactive button with authentication

Tags: slack

What I'm trying to accomplish?

- Send an API (chat.postMessage) from a 3rd party app to a Slack user - Done
- The message will have two buttons (approve and decline) which the user can click on - Done
- Upon clicking on one of the buttons, Slack should send an API back to the 3rd party app - **TBD**

Before sending an API, Slack should retrieve an authentication token via API - **TBD**

Note: I've seen in Slack docs mentioning of /incoming endpoint (also /interactive-message). My 3rd party app has a strict set of available APIs. I'm not able to create new API endpoints. Also, I need the payload to be sent in a specific JSON structure.

I've reviewed Slack documentation but I can't figure it out.
[Making notifications actionable](https://api.slack.com/best-practices/blueprints/actionable-notifications)

I'm technical but not a developer so there might be nuances which I'm missing.

Is there any section in Slack where I can add custom code to accomplish such integration?

If not, how I can accomplish it?

**Edit**:

I've configured a **Request URL** (in slack), when I click on one of the buttons in the message, I can see an API request is being sent to the URL.
I'm able to see the payload as well.

My problem is that I need the information to be sent in a different format and to a different endpoint.
What is the best approach to take for this? Do I need to develop a new service to capture and parse the payload and then generate the API request to my 3rd party app?

[image: Interactivity and Shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is how I've accomplished it.

Upon clicking a button in slack, Slack sends an API with a certain payload to the predefined endpoint which you configure (Request URL).

I've used free tier AWS serverless components:
API Gateway and Lambda

API gateway receives the payload and invokes the Lambda function (I used Python as it seems the easier for a non developer)

My Lambda function is processing the payload and has the logic to interact with my 3rd party app in the required way.